# SQL Server Float data type calculation vs decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, floating-point, decimal, floating-accuracy

In the following query

```
declare @a float(23)
declare @b float(23)
declare @c float(53)
set @a = 123456789012.1234
set @b = 1234567.12345678
set @c = @a * @b
select @c

select LTRIM(STR((@c),32,12))

declare @x  decimal(16,4)
declare @y decimal(16,8)
declare @z decimal (32,12)

set @x = 123456789012.1234
set @y = 1234567.12345678
set @z = @x * @y
select @z
```

I get answers as

```
1.52415693411713E+17
152415693411713020.000000000000
152415692881907790.143935926652
```

From the above answers the third answer is the correct one. Is this the reason why float data type is called Approximate Numeric Data Type

Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong.

BTW this is due to a problem I have with legacy system wherein I have to use float as storage data type, at the same time in there should not be loss of precision while calculation.

Please suggest alternatives, or an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Float is accurate to [15 significant figures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) only (in SQL Server).

This is demonstrated by `1.52415693411713 E+17` where `1.52415693411713` (15 digits) is as accurate as you'll get. The final `020...` after `152415693411713` with `STR` is <strike>**made up**</strike> is the *resolution of floating point*

To keep precision, don't use float. It is that simple. CAST to decimal if you want for calculation, but if you CAST back to float you *are* limited to 15 digits

See ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: thanks for the explanation. this leads us to a possible solution to increase precision while storing the float data type using decimal

Comment: @gbn: There is nothing 'made up' about the extra digits beyond digit 15. For example, 1.23456789012345 converts to a double as 1.0011110000001100101001000010100011000101100111011101, which equals exactly 1.2345678901234500290939877231721766293048858642578125.

Comment: @Rick Regan: This isn't "1.23456789012345" which you'd expect. "made up" is practical enough

Comment: @gbn: I agree a user would want to see "1.23456789012345" in this case. But saying 'made up' only perpetuates the myth that floating point gives unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

The last answer

```
152415692881907790.143935926652
```

is providing scale up to 12 decimal places because you have declared @z accordingly.

```
declare @z decimal (32,12)
```

The second parameter in this declaration is scale which is set to 12.

More on the this can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: How does this explian the float issues, or address OP's accuracy question

Answer (score 0):

Problem not with float Data type.
Problem is with using float(23).
This data type has a capacity of holding 8 significant digits, not 15 as float(53).
And that's exactly how many correct digits you've got in the output.

Calculation of 2 float(23) numbers is done with float(23) precision, and only afterwards converted to float(53), which is absolutely useless and misleading.

Fix the initial declarations of @a and @b and the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Always check what is the value to have actually assigned to a variable:

```
declare @a float(23)
declare @b float(23)
declare @c float(23)

set @a = 123456789012.1234
set @b = 1234567.12345678
SET @c = @a * @b 

select @a, @b, @c

GO 

declare @a float
declare @b float
declare @c float

set @a = 123456789012.1234
set @b = 1234567.12345678
SET @c = @a * @b 

select @a, @b, @c

GO 

The outputs of the SELECTs:

1.234568E+11    1234567     1.524157E+17

123456789012.123    1234567.12345678    1.52415692881908E+17
```

P.S. Operations of 2nd level (multiplication, division) and upper on decimal values use float point computing, so they cannot be any more precise than same operations on FLOAT values, assuming the same level of depth used for both types.