# What's the correct data type I should use in this case?

Tags: c#, sql-server, types, entity-framework-4, sqldatatypes

I have to represent numbers in my database, which are amounts of chemical substances in food, like fats, energy, magnesium and others. These values are decimals in format 12345.67.

If I use `decimal (5,2)` as data type in SQL Server, it maps to `Decimal` type in Entity Framework. If I use float as data type in SQL Server, it maps to `Double` in Entity Framework.

I'm not sure what the best data type in SQL Server would have to be, or doesn't it really matter a lot?

EDIT - in my case it should be `decimal(7,2)`, as mentioned in some of the remarks!

Thanks.

Comment: `DECIMAL` is typically preferred - it's not plagued with rounding errors like `FLOAT`

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Comment: if you want precision and have a finite number of expected values after the decimal, use decimal if you don't care about precision use float.   search on decimal vs float to see the reasons why.

Comment: Since the percentage of certain substances in other substances does not have an exact accuracy of 2 digits, decimal is not the proper type here. For instance, you can't put 0.125 in a decimal(5,2) field, but you can in a float. The people suggesting decimal are all thinking about money!

Comment: @Mr Lister: I also think about money (meaning, to save money) :)

Comment: So what's the business requirements? Are you doing math on these chemical substances and need to maintain a level of precision Or are they already "estimates" due to having to drop "insignificant" digits.  If already dropping insignificant digits, float would be fine as your values stored are already imprecise. you just need to know you will have to round them when you render results; and the "Pure math" may not add up due to the imprecision of float.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `decimal(7,2)`

- 7 is total number of digits
- 2 is after the decimal point

Differences:

- float is *approximate* and will give unexpected results
- decimal is *exact*

References:

- [Accuracy problem with floating numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)
- [SQL Server Float data type calculation vs decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8414561/27535)

Comment: Thank you. I read that Decimal is the most precise type, but if i use Decimal(7,2), does it mean that not a lot of storage is needed in sql server? In that case, I also read that Decimal is the slowest to work with in .NET, can this become a problem if I need these numbers in calculations?

Comment: @Lud: decimal(7,2) requires 9 bytes storage. float is 8 bytes. Not much difference given accuracy. I wouldn't worry about performance in .net unless you have vast amounts of data. Even then, the .net math handling of double is far better than SQL Server so you can store decimal in the database but process double in.net if needed

Comment: @Cicada, don't understand your comment... it's a business app, so..?

Comment: @Lud I mean monetary / finance, not business. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

`DECIMAL(7,2)` would be better than float - it's exactly what you need (5 + 2 digits). With floating types (eg. float, double) you may have some problems - e.g. with rounding.

Comment: Actually: `DECIMAL(5,2)` means: 5 digits **in total** - two of which after the decimal point - so it's really 3+2 digits (**NOT** 5+2)!

Comment: Ok, and wouldn't this cause performance issues in calculations as I read that decimal is the slowest type in .NET?

Comment: DECIMAL(5,2) can only store at a maximum 999.99, it is 5 total digits with a scale of two decimals (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)