# SQL - Rounding up float values to the 2nd decimal place using the away-from-zero midpoint rule

Tags: sql, roundup

I want to round up a number but `CEILING`rounds to first integer. I also tried adding 0.005 but this rounds up the ones under 0.005.

I want to round up if the 3rd decimal is 5 or higher...

please try these numbers before posting your solution

```
  5.085 --> 5.09
 15.085 --> 15.09
110.4646 --> 110.46
110.4656 --> 110.47
```

My Code :

```
DECLARE @i float 
  SET 
    @i = 5.085 
 SELECT 
    ROUND(@i, 1) AS [Result 1], 
    ROUND(@i, 2) AS [Result 2], 
    ROUND(@i, 3) AS [Result 3]
```

result is

[image: result]

Expected result 2 is 5.09 when 3rd decimal is 5 or higher...

Comment: `5.085 - 5.085 =`, when doing decimal minus float,  is not equal to 0 , see:  https://dbfiddle.uk/IGAtq0Fj   (see also: [SQL Server Float data type calculation vs decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414561/sql-server-float-data-type-calculation-vs-decimal))

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if ou convert your float to a higher precision, you can round and it decides alone if with 5 it is get up or with 4 down

```
    DECLARE @i float ,  @j float
      SET 
        @i = 5.085 
      SET @j = 0.084
     SELECT 
        ROUND(CAST(@i as float(3)), 1,0) AS [Result 1],     
      ROUND(CAST(@i as float(3)), 2,0) AS [Result 2],
      ROUND(CAST(@j as float(3)), 2,0) AS [Result 2],
        ROUND(CAST(@i as float(3)), 3,0) AS [Result 3],
        ROUND(CAST(@j as float(3)), 3,0) AS [Result 3]
```

| Result 1 | Result 2 | Result 2 | Result 3 | Result 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5.1 | 5.09 | 0.08 | 5.085 | 0.084 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Er8yau_k)

Comment: it should decide automatically, if the 3rd decimal is 5 or more , it should round up, if not down... `5.085` --> `5.09` but `115.4646` --> `115.46`

Comment: then i misunderstood ou i changed my answer, to show how you can simply do it in an universal solution

Comment: thank you. my last solution was also similar... `Round(CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 4), @i), 2)`

Comment: Cde inal needs to be adapted here you need only value and which figir you want to reduce

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting to work with a decimal, use a *decimal* data type:

```
DECLARE @i Decimal(4,3) = 5.085 
SELECT 
  ROUND(@i, 1) AS [Result 1], 
  ROUND(@i, 2) AS [Result 2], 
  ROUND(@i, 3) AS [Result 3]
```

[image: Result]

Comment: the original data in SQL is float but i can CAST it to decimal...

Comment: This is not clear in your question however yes just cast it as a decimal data type to get the expected rounding behaviour; `float` is almost certainly the wrong data type to be using.

Comment: try with number 115.4646. the result should be 115.46 but your solution gives 115.47

Comment: simply converting solves the problem actually... `convert(Decimal(18,2),@i)`

Comment: You need to specify the approprial scale and precision, the above answer is based soley on your sample data. Using `DECLARE @i Decimal(7,4) = 115.4646` works

Comment: when i try `5.085` i get the result `5.08` but when i try `15.085` i get the result as `15.09` what is the difference ? 

Comment: please check my revised answer....

Answer (score -1):

this is the solution i found with the help of @Stu ... i tried with several sample numbers, so far this works...

```
DECLARE @i FLOAT = 5.4646
DECLARE @x DECIMAL(38, 4)
DECLARE @y DECIMAL(38, 4)

SET @x = CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 4), @i)
SET @y = Cast(@i AS DECIMAL(38, 4))

SELECT @x                                    'Converted Number',
       @y                                    'Casted Number',
       Round(@x, 2)                          'Rounded Convert',
       Round(@y, 2)                          'Rounded Cast',
       Round(CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 4), @i), 2) 'My Solution'
```

[image: result]